# C#, Is there a map structure?

Tags: c#

In c# is there a structure like c++ map?  I have a group of numbers like this:

1.234 1
5.789 0
3.445 1
...

where the I need to sort the data based on the smallest number in column one, but I need column one numbers to stay with each respected number in column two.  So after sorting it would look like this:

1.234 1
3.445 1
5.789 0
...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

```
SortedDictionary<Double,Int>
```

Answer (score 6):

[SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

Here are the remarks:

> Each key/value pair can be retrieved
>   as a KeyValuePair(TKey, TValue)
>   structure, or as a DictionaryEntry
>   through the nongeneric IDictionary
>   interface.
>
> Keys must be immutable as long as they
>   are used as keys in the
>   SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue). Every
>   key in a SortedDictionary(TKey,
>   TValue) must be unique. A key cannot
>   be a null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic), but a value can be, if the
>   value type TValue is a reference type.
>
> SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue)
>   requires a comparer implementation to
>   perform key comparisons. You can
>   specify an implementation of the
>   IComparer(T) generic interface by
>   using a constructor that accepts a
>   comparer parameter; if you do not
>   specify an implementation, the default
>   generic comparer Comparer(T).Default
>   is used. If type TKey implements the
>   System.IComparable(T) generic
>   interface, the default comparer uses
>   that implementation.

You can try [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) as well.

Comment: You do know it says `© 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.` at the bottom of those pages.

Comment: I suspect the odds of Microsoft complaining about a clearly referenced quote from their copyrighted help documentation are quite minimal...

Comment: The quote's a bit longer than I personally would like to see, but it  probably falls under fair use/right to quote.  Of course, I Am Not A Lawyer so YMMV.

Comment: When the original comment was made it was twice as long.

Comment: @Simeon: Ahhh...strange thing is I don't see any edits.  Could there have been a delete followed by a new answer?